# Pause a linux kernel function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I was using Jprobe to monitoring a kernel function and the final goal is to pause the function on some conditions. I got the Jprobe no problem, I am having trouble pausing the function.

Currently I have tried to pause the pid, which failed because the process is paused for sure but the kernel function does not pause. It still finished the job which is not what I want.

My best hope is hijack the kernel function, so that I can do whatever I like with the function. I found some articles about this, but most of them are out of date, the kernel changed a lot after 2.6. I got the idea of I should find the function's address and change the first some bytes to jump to my new function. I am having problem finding this address. Anyone know how to do this? Or is there another easier way to pause the function?

Edit: I was trying to use the address that I find from System.map or /proc/kallsyms which the results are the same, but error came up. Seems like doing this after kernel 2.6 is not easy, anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Why not System.map ????

Comment: Is System.map and /proc/kallsyms the same thing? Sorry I am new to kernel.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest doing this with either a virtualization setup or hardware-supported remote debugging (as with JTag).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to simply pause and inspect a kernel function, user mode linux may be appropriate.  It's admittedly an older mechanism, but doing something simple like this using uml is well documented.  Here are a couple links to get you started:

- http://web2.clarkson.edu/class/cs644/kernel/setup/uml/gdb_uml.html
- http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/hacking.html

This answer also discusses using uml as well as some alternatives (including additional links):

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9330/kernel-hacking-environment

Comment: I want to achieve this goal with normal linux.
"Here are some of the things that UML is used for:
Hosting of virtual servers,
Kernel development,
Experimenting with new kernels and distributions,
Education,
Sandbox."

Answer (score 0):

```
I am having problem finding this address. Anyone know how to do this?
```

From **kprobes** implementation,

```
static kprobe_opcode_t __kprobes *kprobe_addr(struct kprobe *p)
1355 {
1356         kprobe_opcode_t *addr = p->addr;
1357 
1358         if ((p->symbol_name && p->addr) ||
1359             (!p->symbol_name && !p->addr))
1360                 goto invalid;
1361 
1362         if (p->symbol_name) {
1363                 kprobe_lookup_name(p->symbol_name, addr);
1364                 if (!addr)
1365                         return ERR_PTR(-ENOENT);
1366         }
1367 
1368         addr = (kprobe_opcode_t *)(((char *)addr) + p->offset);
1369         if (addr)
1370                 return addr;
1371 
1372 invalid:
1373         return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);
1374 }
```

This will definitely will help you.

Usually `p->symbol_name` will be passed with kernel symbols. for example, `p->symbol_name = "kmalloc"`.

This function kprobe_addr() will gives the corresponding address.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kprobes.c?a=arm#L1354